# Azure Web App Websockets CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing an API (using Node.js) and use Socket.io with Express, I been presented some errors with CORS, I resolved with Express and Socket.io 2.0 in localhost, this worked with *.azurewebsites.net but anymore works.

Testing for Express (see console): http://crawlerbackend.azurewebsites.net/test_cors_express_azure.html

Testing for Socket.io (see console): http://crawlerbackend.azurewebsites.net/test_cors_socketio_azure.html

But I need expose my Socket.io API to everybody because my clients requiere it, and tested the same files in Heroku:

Testing for Express (see console): https://testcrawlersite.herokuapp.com/test_cors_express_azure.html

Testing for Socket.io (see console): https://testcrawlersite.herokuapp.com/test_cors_socketio_azure.html

I follow best Express and Socket.io practices according with their documentation. I have an unique conclusion, I need a configuration in IISNode? or in portal? different as the option "CORS" (is set with *).[image: fake configuration?]

This is the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://crawlerbackend.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LmW1TfL. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://testcrawlersite.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enable `Web Sockets` to let Socket.io use WebSockets instead of long polling. There is no same-origin policy for WebSockets.

To enable WebSockets by using the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), click the web app from the Web Apps blade, click **All settings** > **Application settings**. Under **Web Sockets**, click **On**. Then click **Save**.

For more info, please refer to [Create a Node.js chat application with Socket.IO in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio).